# robots.txt content / selenium web scraping

Tags: robots.txt

I am trying to run web scraping using selenium

What does this robot.txt content mean?

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /go/
Disallow: /launch-announcement/
```

Can i run web scraping in all folders except go and launch-announcement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What is a robots.txt file?**

Robots.txt is a text file webmasters create to instruct web robots (typically search engine robots) how to crawl pages on their website. The robots.txt file is part of the the robots exclusion protocol (REP), a group of web standards that regulate how robots crawl the web, access and index content, and serve that content up to users. The REP also includes directives like meta robots, as well as page-, subdirectory-, or site-wide instructions for how search engines should treat links (such as “follow” or “nofollow”).

In practice, robots.txt files indicate whether certain user agents (web-crawling software) can or cannot crawl parts of a website. These crawl instructions are specified by “disallowing” or “allowing” the behavior of certain (or all) user agents. [view more...](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt)

*The **Disallow:** tells the robot that it should not visit the mentioned page on the site.*

*Can i run web scraping in all folders except go and launch-announcement?*

**Yes** you can scrape the other page except these 2.

Comment: so  its allowed to visit the pages which are not mentioned disallowed section of the robots.txt ?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [basic robots.txt guide](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961), the rule-

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /go/
Disallow: /launch-announcement/
```

means crawling `/go/` and `/launch-announcement/` (and their subdirectories) is disallowed for **all** user agents.

Comment: so crawling is allowed on other pages rite ? i knw common sense says so .

Comment: @Anti_cse51 yes